# Where is UIView convenient initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

I am new to ios development.

In Xcode, I can find UIView has two initializer.

```
 @available(iOS 2.0, *)
 open class UIView : UIResponder, NSCoding, UIAppearance, UIAppearanceContainer, UIDynamicItem, UITraitEnvironment, UICoordinateSpace, UIFocusItem, CALayerDelegate {


     open class var layerClass: Swift.AnyClass { get } // default is [CALayer class]. Used when creating the underlying layer for the view.


     // default is [CALayer class]. Used when creating the underlying layer for the view.

     public init(frame: CGRect)

     public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)


     ......
 }
```

here is my questions.

- in a open class, `public init(frame: CGRect)` has no method body?
  I think only protocol can have empty implementation.
- in RCTViewManager, we always create a UIView without parameters

code

```
 override func view() -> UIView! {
     let ins = CustomUIView()
     return ins;
 }
```

where is this convenient initializer defined? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> in a open class, `public init(frame: CGRect)` has no method body?
>   I think only protocol can have empty implementation.

`init(frame: CGRect)` *does* have a method body. It is just not shown. What you're seeing is the *interface* of `UIView`. What you *want* to see is the source code of `UIView`, which I don't think you can get.

> in RCTViewManager, we always create a UIView without parameters. where is this convenient initializer defined? I can't find it anywhere.

Since almost everything in `UIKit` extends `NSObject`, almost everything inherit the parameterless constructor that's defined in `NSObject`:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. The file xcode jump to is UIKit.UIVIEW.swift, it is not implementation? I thought in swift ,  the interface and implementation are already merged together.

Answer (score 1):

UIView subclasses UIResponder which is a subclass of NSObject. NSObject has an initializer as

```
    public init()
```

So here you don't need a convenient initializer. I hope this answers your question.